# able to change value in const pointers

Tags: c, pointers, gcc

After running the below program:

```
gcc -c volVars.c -o volv

./volv
```

it compiles.

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main(){
    printf("study of volatile pointers\n");
    const int lConstInt=6;
    printf("\n const int is %d\n",lConstInt);
    volatile const int *lvcint=&lConstInt;
    printf("volatile const int after assignment = %d\n",*lvcint);
    //*lvcint=*lvcint+1; uncommenting this gives compilation error  
    int *track = lvcint;
    *track = *track + 1;
    printf("modified the lcoation = %d\n",*track);
}
```

if i uncomment `lvcint=*lvcint+1;` line it gives error as expected. But if I refer to that pointer (`lvcint`) using track which is non const I can modify its content. I get warning at that line but finally I am able to modify the content of read only location. Is there any bug in gcc or there is something I am missing.

Comment: Good Read: [How to change the constness of a variable in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13618706/how-to-change-the-constness-of-a-variable-in-c)

Comment: Everyone needs to pay attention to compiler warnings.

Comment: A conforming C compiler is only forced to issue a "diagnostic" if you violate the rules. You say that you see a warning, then it is your fault do ignore that warning.

Answer (score 0):

Roughly speaking, the `const` keyword is (only) a good practise which might prevent some potential bugs, also it may trigger better compilation optimizations.

But it does not actually protect the variables, like permission bits do.

Sometimes compilers may put constant variables in the read-only segments of the binary, and writing to them would trigger exceptions like invalid memory access, but you cannot rely on this.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a bug in gcc, it does issue a warning in this case and you should always pay attention to warnings.

Changing the value of a `const` variable generates undefined behavior, which based on the standard means you can't know what will happen. It might behave completely different on different machines, compilers, states of the program or of the system, phases of the moon.
It's usually up to the developer to keep away from undefined behavior, the compiler can't figure out all possible cases and issue errors.

Answer (score 0):

Under Linux, I get the following warning:

> warning: initialization discards ‘const volatile’ qualifier from
>   pointer target type [enabled by default]

Which I think means that the compiler actually removes the const qualifiers and initializes them normally. I can't say for sure though but it's my best guess since this code refuses to compile in GCC under Windows. I get an the following error in Windows:

> "error: invalid conversion from 'const volatile int*' to 'int*'

So yeah, I'd have to guess the code was modified by the compiler.

As to why that line you commented out causes an error, it's because you can't modify a constant (well you shouldn't be able to).

Sources: My own experimentation.